# Replace text using Oracle PL/SQL regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

I would like to replace a text stored in an Oracle table using PL/SQL. The column data type is varchar. I am looking for a regular expression to replace the GUID in the text highlighted in bold.

Below is a sample text

*Before string replace:*
...javascript:setCookie('setcookielink','applicationpath/entity/performaction.action?**did=7e78fae65cddc6c912b5de6c6582cf22**_entity&queryonly...

*After string replace:*
...javascript:setCookie('setcookielink','applicationpath/entity/performaction.action?**did=123456789**_entity&queryonly...

Is there a way to achieve the desired result in PL/SQL?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
with test as
( select 'javascript:setCookie(''setcookielink''','''applicationpath/entity/performaction.action?did=7e78fae65cddc6c912b5de6c6582cf22_entity&queryonly''' data from dual 
)
select regexp_replace(data, 'did\=[0-9a-z]*','did=123456789') from test
```

This is just straight sql, no pl/sql needed, and see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm)